# Получить значение из поля в HTML и передать его в JS

Tags: javascript, html

В два поля нужно ввести значения, затем нажать на кнопку и вывести значение суммы этих двух чисел на HTML.

Не могу передать значения с двух полей в JS.

И почему-то на такое выражение `let a = document.getElementById("inpt1").value` ругается.

```js
let f;
let a = document.getElementById("inpt1");
console.log('Объявлена переменная а: ' + a);
let b = document.getElementById("inpt2");
console.log('Объявлена переменная b: ' + b);

document.getElementById('ks').addEventListener('click', f1);
if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
  function f1(a, b) {
    f = a + b;
    return (f);
  }
} else {
  alert('Tchet ne to vse, ne tak rabotaet');
}
(function f2() {
  window.onload = function f3() {
    document.getElementById('SMA').innerHTML = f;
  }
})();
```

```html
<div>
  Поле ввода переменной "а" : <br>
  <input id="inpt1" type="text" size="5">
  <p></p>
  Поле ввода переменной "b" : <br>
  <input id="inpt2" type="text" size="5">
  <p></p>
  <input id="ks" type="button" value="Вычислить сумму"> br>
  По нажатию на кнопку выполяется дейтвие с отображением результата br>
  <h4>Ниже отображается сумма вычисления :</h4>
  <div class="style1" id="SMA">Это переменная с id</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жесть конечно у вас там творится, комментировать не буду, просто приведу рабочий пример.

```js
document.getElementById('ks').onclick=()=>{
  var [a,b]=[Number(document.querySelector('#inpt1').value), Number(document.querySelector('#inpt2').value)];
  document.querySelector('#SMA').innerText=a+b;
};
```

```html
<html>
    <script src="p3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="p3.css">
    <header>
        <title>
            Сумма двух алертов)
        </title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div>
            Поле ввода переменной "а" : </br>
            <input id="inpt1" type="text" size="5"></input>
            <p></p>
            Поле ввода переменной "b" : </br>
            <input id="inpt2" type="text" size="5"></input>
            <p></p>
            <input  id="ks" type="button" value="Вычислить сумму"></br>
            По нажатию на кнопку выполяется дейтвие с отображением результата</br>
            <h4>Ниже отображается сумма вычисления :</h4>
            <div class="style1" id="SMA">Это переменная с id</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Какой ужас, какой ужас, но комментировать не буду.

Comment: И правильно я сам в шоке =)

Comment: если хотите помочь человеку, то объясните все его недостатки в данном примере, чтобы в будущем он не ошибался, то, что вы решили задачу - молодцы, но толку от этого 0

Comment: Да там с самого начала надо объяснять, с начала разметки в JS, тело функции не пишется в условных блоках.

Comment: Сильно не ругайте, только учусь.Спасибо.